# Thinkpad T470 touchpad buttons not working after upgrading to Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, thinkpad

The machine is freshly bought and I upgraded its system from the pre-installed Windows 10 Home Single Language Edition to Windows 10 Pro via the windows store and after that the touchpad buttons don't respond to clicking or pressing or whatsoever at all. I couldn't find anywhere this problem has been addressed. What are the possible causes and solutions?

[image: pic of touchpad buttons]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by updating its mouse and keyboard driver: [Drivers & Software](http://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t470/downloads)

Comment: The same issue came back after updating to Windows 10 1909 (just a few days ago) - I have updated all Lenovo drivers in my T450 but it's still not working.

Comment: @WestRay Yep, it came back to me recently and I have to check this answer again. After reinstalling the said drivers from the same page above it still doesn't work. Seems a little too buggy...

Comment: These keys are working well on my Linux OS though.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you do not need this information now but maybe it will help someone.
I bought t470 and had the same problem with stock win 10 pro. I thought about sending it back but I uninstalled touch driver and probably now windows uses some default one. I have almost fully working touchpad with buttons (of course there is no fancy functionalities like shrinking touch area).

Comment: Look at my answer :)

Comment: [ivanhjc](https://superuser.com/users/435483/ivanhjc) thanks

Answer (score -1):

Download the latest Ultranav driver from lenovo. The trick is to find the C:\DRIVERS\UltraNav\SynPD.inf file in the directory the driver extracts to. right click and choose "install" it will prompt restart computer. It should work afterwards.